# Typescript imitation problems

Tags: typescript, oop

Hi I have the following error in typescript:

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.init();
    }

    public init() {
        console.log('a')
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor(public text) {
        super();
    }
    public init() {
        console.log(this.text)
    }
}

new B('text');
```

The console writes undefined.
What can be done to overcome it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the `super()` call is the first thing that's called when you call `new B('text')`, the super call immediately calls `this.init()`, since `this` is an instance of `B`, not `A`, it tries to call `console.log(this.text)` and not `console.log('text')`. But `this.text` is only set *after* the super call, not before.

This is why you should not do work in the constructor. **Until the constructor had completely finished running, your object is not ready for action**.

You should remove the `init()` call from the parent's constructor, and call it separately, like so:

```
class A {
    public init() {
        console.log('a')
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor(public text: string) {
        super(); // no longer strictly needed, as parent has no constructor anymore.
    }
    public init() {
        console.log(this.text)
    }
}

const b = new B('text');
// only now the object is ready.
b.init();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class B extends A {
    public text:string;
    constructor(public text) {
        super();
        this.text = text;
    }
    public init() {
        console.log(this.text)
    }
}
```

try it like this

Comment: Does not work.
 Duplicate identifier 'text'.